# I want to compare my prediction value with original train data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikits

I am trying to learn decision tree regressor and I have wrote below code.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( 
          x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)
model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

I want to create a dataframe which include X_test and Y_test and Y_pred.
Is there any method or function for that.

[image: I want something like this]

Answer (score 1):

Append the below code at the end of your prediction code:

```
final_df = X_test.copy()
final_df["Y_original"] = y_test
final_df["Y_predicted"] = y_pred
```

Here we are creating a new dataframe namely `final_df` and putting all the values you require into it. Would not suggest you to directly append values into `X_test`, as it might be needed for use again for prediction.